# Div tags not showing up in jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, hidden

I have a menu that when I click on a button a div box appears as the corresponding option. It works great but the only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to allow the divs I place inside the boxes to show up instead of being shown as `display:hidden.`

I've tried adding `.css("display","block");` to it but that just made things a bit crazy. Here's the current spot I'm sitting at: [FIDDLE](http://tinyurl.com/csbzhkd).

If any changes to the CSS or JS is made could you please let me know what it is you changed to get it to work?

I've even added some divs in the first and second box to show that they're not showing up.

Comment: I've changed the internal divs (the big and bold, and the black box) to P tags instead. now they work... Sorry, i'm not an expert in javascript so i can't help further (hence this is a comment and not an answer)

Comment: Thank you @STT LCU for the nifty workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took me awhile to figure out what you were asking, your css is pushing everything far to the right, but I think this is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/GbMRx/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var el = $('#cnt' + this.id.replace('btn', ''));
        $('#content-new div').not(el).animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 100).hide();
        el.toggle();
        el.children("div").toggle();
    });
});
```

i just toggled the children as well.

another option (probably the better option) would be to only hide/toggle the first level children... http://jsfiddle.net/GbMRx/4/

JS:

```
        $('#content-new > div').not(el).animate({...
```

CSS: (removed `display:none` from `#content-new div` and added this)

```
#content-new>div {
    display:none;
}
```

...and I got to thinking, you probably only meant to affect only the first level child divs in the first place? If that is true, this is probably what you want... same as above except just making all the `#content-new div`'s into `#content-new>div` ... http://jsfiddle.net/GbMRx/5/

Comment: Yes, I believe you were only wanting your `#content-new div` CSS to only be applied to first level children. That actually applies to ANY div at any level within #content-new, including 'grandchildren'... the `>` in `#content-new>div` means it only applies to first level children... your jquery selector without the `>` was doing the same